# Detailed dependency analysis between eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin A that depends on another plugin B. I'd like to know which methods of any class in B are called from anywhere in A. Is there a way to generate such a report in eclipse?

Comment: If something in plugin A calls methods of an interface and the interface is implemented in plugin B and plugin C you can't tell if this is a dependency on B or not. Other things like JFace data binding use reflection which make it very difficult to determine dependencies.

Comment: That's correct, but not that relevant to my situation. My plugin B is a model plugin generated from an ecore model so interfaces I'm interested in and their implementations are all in the same plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the plug-in B in `Dependencies` tab of MANIFEST editor of plug-in A and choose `Compute Dependency Extent`

Comment: That seems like step in the right direction. However, it only gives me the referenced classes but no information about which methods are called.